# Getting access denied error when loading a mysql table from a .csv file on server

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to load the table with .csv file using the following :

```
$query3="LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/xampp/htdocs/schoolonweb/trainee/views/sliptest/sliptestuploads/$filename' INTO TABLE $sliptesttable (SchoolId,ClassId,SectionId,SubjectId,NewSubjectId,SlipTestId,StudentId,Mark)";
```

where the $filename is of **.csv** format but  am getting the following

```
**error** : Access denied for user 'babc'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

The username and password is correct as i am able to log in to the server with the same credentials.
Can somebody help ?

Comment: Anyway - check the password.

Comment: next, check your permissions

Comment: Worked !! USe  DATA LOCAL INFILE...